# Chat Button Display During Hours of Operation

Tags: javascript, time, utc

I am trying to get a chat button to display during hours of operation and then a closed statement to display after hours.

I am able to get it to display the chat button only but it doesn't go away after hours.

Hours of operation are 6:30AM - 3:30PM Central Time

Thanks in advance!

```
  var openingTime = new Date();
  openingTime.getUTCHours(11); openingTime.getUTCMinutes(30);


  var closingTime = new Date();
  closingTime.getUTCHours(20); closingTime.getUTCMinutes(30);

var d = new Date();

if(((d.getUTCHours() >= openingTime.getUTCHours() && d.getUTCHours() <= closingTime.getUTCHours() ) && (d.getUTCDay() >= 1 && d.getUTCDay() <= 5) )) {
    $(".open").show();
    $(".closed").hide();
}
else {  
     $(".closed").show();
    $(".open").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code, I see that you are using [getUTCHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours) and [getUTCMinutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes) to set the hour and minute. However these two methods are only for getting the hour and minute from the Date object.

Instead use [setUTCHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) and [setUTCMinutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCMinutes) to set the hour and minute

This might not be the root of the problem, but it's a small error I found when reading the code.

Hope it helps.